# Problem to plot data from external json file into highchart?

Tags: php, json, highcharts, extract

I extract data from my mysqli db into JSON file like this.:

````
<?php
session_start();
include_once("../config.php");

$Name13 = $_SESSION['RNaam'];

$conn = new mysqli($servername ,$username, $password, $db);
$sqli = "SELECT  * FROM metingen where Id > '20000' and Lijn ='Lijn 2' and FlakeType1 ='FLK PE DSD329 0216 P2S2' AND KleurL BETWEEN '60'AND '80' ORDER BY Id asc";
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sqli);

//$rows = array();
$rows['metingen'] = 'metingen';
$rows['Datum'] = 'Datum';
while($r1 =  mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
  $rows['data'][] = $r1['Datum'];
  $rows['data'][] = $r1['KleurL'];

   }


$result2 = array();
//array_push($result2,$data);
array_push($result2,$rows);

print json_encode($result2, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

$conn->close();
?>```


The result of my JSON looks like this.:
````

[{"metingen":"metingen","Datum":"Datum","data":["17-1-2022",77.42,"17-1-2022",77.46,"17-1-2022",75.71,"17-1-2022",78.37,"18-1-2022",78.86,"18-1-2022",78.41,"18-1-2022",76.51,"18-1-2022",76.03,"18-1-2022",75.48,"18-1-2022",75.6,"18-1-2022",75.25,"18-1-2022",76.53,"18-1-2022",78.01,"18-1-2022",77.63,"18-1-2022",78.51,"18-1-2022",78.67,"19-1-2022",76.16,"19-1-2022",75.38,"19-1-2022",75.55,"19-1-2022",73.71,"19-1-2022",76.91,"19-1-2022",77.25,"19-1-2022",78,"19-1-2022",77.81,"19-1-2022",77.65,"22-1-2022",77.21,"22-1-2022",76.97,"22-1-2022",77.43,"22-1-2022",78.08,"22-1-2022",75.76,"22-1-2022",76.12,"23-1-2022",76.07,"23-1-2022",76.32,"23-1-2022",77.43,"23-1-2022",77.97,"23-1-2022",78.03,"23-1-2022",77.86,"23-1-2022",76.41,"23-1-2022",76.69,"23-1-2022",76.44,"23-1-2022",76.4,"24-1-2022",76.2,"24-1-2022",75.97,"24-1-2022",76.85,"24-1-2022",76.2,"24-1-2022",77.56,"1-2-2022",74.88.......```

The page with highcharts looks like this.:

````
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<?php
session_start();

?>
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        if(!window.location.hash) {
                window.location = window.location + '#loaded';
                window.location.reload();
        }
}

</script>
<html>
    <head>
        <?php
        echo '<!-- <meta http-Equiv="Cache-Control" Content="no-cache">   -->';
        echo '<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">';
        echo '<meta http-Equiv="Pragma" Content="no-cache">';
        echo '<meta http-Equiv="Expires" Content="0">';
        ?>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Grafiek</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/data.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var chart;
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.getJSON("datatest01112022.php", function(json) {
                    /*options.series[0].name = json[0]['Reg_sample'];
                    options.series[0].data = json[0]['KleurL'];*/
                    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                        chart: {
                            renderTo: 'container2',
                            type: 'line',
                            marginRight: 130,
                            marginBottom: 100
                            },
                            title: {
                                text: 'Gemeten L* waarde van Prep 2 bij Extrusie 2',
                                x: -20 //center
                                },
                                subtitle: {text: '',x: -20},
                                    xAxis: {  title: {
                                                text: 'Datum'
                                                }},
                                        yAxis: {
                                            title: {
                                                text: 'KleurL'
                                                },
                                                plotLines: [{
                                                    value: 0,
                                                    width: 1,
                                                    color: '#808080'
                                                    }]
                                                    },
                                                    tooltip: {
                                                        formatter: function() {
                                                            //return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                                                            return '<b>Meetwaarden</b><br/>'+
                                                            this.x +': '+ this.y;
                                                            }
                                                            },
                                                            legend: {layout: 'vertical',align: 'right',verticalAlign: 'top',x: -10,y: 100,borderWidth: 0},
                                                                yAxis: {
                                                                    plotLines: [{value: 70,color: 'red',dashStyle: 'longdashdot',width: 2,label: {text: 'Minimum'}},
                                                                                {value: 80,color: 'red',dashStyle: 'longdashdot',width: 2,label: {text: 'Maximum'}},
                                                                                {value: 75,color: 'green',dashStyle: 'shortdash',width: 2,label: {text: 'Richtlijn'         },
                                                                                            }]
                                                                                            },
                                                                                            series: json,
                                                                                            });
                                                                                            });
                                                                                            });
                                                                                             });
        </script>
    </head>
<body>



<div id="container2" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">  </div>
<!--<script src="highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>-->


</body>
</html>```


Why dosn't plot the highcharts the values and put the date/time into the x-axis in the line, but if i remove the date/time from my JSON file it works?

Can anybody solve my problem?
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adapt your data to the format required by Highcharts. In your case, it can be an array of arrays, each with two values.

```
data: [
    [0, 1],
    [1, 2],
    [2, 8]
]
```

You should do that in your php script, but you can also use JS part:

```
  const processedData = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < json[0].data.length; i += 2) {
    processedData.push([json[0].data[i], json[0].data[i + 1]]);
  }

  json[0].data = processedData;
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/35cem86h/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data

Comment: I don't know if i must start a new question if it goes about your answer so i hear it if its wrong from my part. In your code the for-loop takes all data into processeddata. Is it possible to take from those values a average so i can check this in my console?

Comment: Hi @Pascal, What do you exactly mean? How do you want to calculate the average?

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, Well i need some calculation in my chart as titel. Calculation of the average of all values works, i do the test in the console to see if it works, now i only need to find out how i can calculate Cpk high and low and cp. Lot of codes to find but till now i can't get them to work :S

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. By keeping the right structure, you can provide any data to the chart, so you just need to calculate the values that you need.